# Power button is not responsive when being hold on LG Optimus F3

Tags: lg, buttons

I have an LG Optimus F3. Last night, I wanted to screenshot something, but holding the power button didn't do anything. I can press it and the screen would turn on/off, but there's no response when holding it.

I tried holding it for a good 1 minute, but it still isn't working.

How to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by the power button will not hold ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You know how you hold the power button to see the option to Restart, Factory Reset, etc. When I hold the power button that doesn't show. It's like I'm not holding it. Do you kind of understand now?

Comment: Yeah, got it, could it be a hardware issue with the button ? Can you turn on your phone ? (Don't try it if you haven't already, since if it's a hardware issue you won't be able to turn it back on)

Comment: Yes I can turn the phone on & off.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, can you dial <hash><star><hash><star>7594<star><hash><star><hash>, I'm not sure it works on LG phones, it gives an option to change the power button behavior. Since extended discussions are not recommended in the comments session, I will do some research and get back to you as soon as I can

Comment: omg. I fixed ! I had to remove the batteries and put it back inside lol. but thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @Brenda Glad you found a solution! Please, answer your own question and then accept your own answer, so others can *see* it's solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is a routine issue for me.

Removing the battery to force a reboot temporarily fixes the problem. I haven't found a permanent solution though.